# Populating a dictionary using two strings to generate the key-value pair

Tags: python

I have two strings (of the same length) and I want to create a dictionary where the keys are the characters in one string having values corresponding to the characters in the other string.

```
x='qwert'
y='asdfg'
```

Then, the dictionary should contain

```
d[q]='a'
d[w]='s'
d[e]='d'
d[r]='f'
d[t]='g'
```

I tried doing something like this

```
for i,j in x,y:
   d[i]=j
```

But this doesn't seem to work in python ( as it would have in C ).
How can I do this ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
d = dict(zip(x, y))
```

Quite a simple solution, you only need to `zip` the two strings together, then pass them into the `dict` constructor.

Breakdown:

- `zip(x, y)` creates a list of tuples that groups the letters that are in the "same position" in the strings.

  ```
  [('q', 'a'), ('w', 's'), ('e', 'd'), ('r', 'f'), ('t', 'g')]
  ```
- `dict()` takes in a list of two element tuples, and makes them a key-value pair in a dictionary.

  ```
  {'q': 'a', 'r': 'f', 'e': 'd', 't': 'g', 'w': 's'}
  ```

  Note that the dictionary doesn't appear in the order of the tuples - that's because dictionaries aren't ordered containers, instead they just map a value to another.

Comment: +1. Python is so simple, yet amazing at some times. Also, congratulations on 6k reputation :)

Comment: I'm stunned at how easy that is. @Haidro congrats on "404" rep. Oh crap, I ruined it.

Comment: Does the dict() constructor work in python 2.7 ?? I keep getting this error : TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable

Comment: It should work. I just tested this code in python 2.7 and it works just fine. @AustinMullins ;)

Comment: @CSSS did you have a `dict` variable? If you did, then you would have overwritten the constructor. Rename it to something else - `d` for example.

Comment: @Volatility: Yeah.. Got it !! Silly Mistakes :)